# Lost hidden images

Tags: storage, files, hidden

I used an app to hide certain images on my phone and I transferred the image folders from the phone to an SD card. Now it's not showing and the folders are empty :( how can I restore them?

Answer (score 0):

Apps I've seen usually hide the images by changing their format and saving them in hidden folders at some random locations.

- You can check the default saving location used by the app in the preferences. Explore the location from a file explorer and backup the file.
- Uninstall the app and reinstall it.
- copy the backed up files into the default location again.
- try unhiding the files again from the app